# Highcharts Point Select/Unselect Events

Tags: events, highcharts, callback

Let's have a simple spline chart created using Highcharts library. Each point on the spline serie is selectable, once you set `plotOptions.spline.allowPointSelect: true`. For each point you can then define `plotOptions.spline.point.events.(un)select: fn(e) {...}` events.

Let's define both select and unselect events, select one point by clicking on it, and then unselect it by selecting a different one. The thing is, that `select` event on *new* point fires before `unselect` event on the *old* point. I would prefer that event `unselect` of the *old* point would fire before `select` event on the *new* point.

Any ideas how to achieve that?

http://jsfiddle.net/2Wr8v/

Comment: Looking at the source code, that's just how it's written (see line 17140).  It is select point then unselect all other selected points.  Can I ask why you need it in a certain order?

Comment: I see the source, thanks. Let's have the jsfiddle example I posted. Imagine you want to show user the label with information about selected point. When user selects the first point, it works fine, when he selects another one, he sees information about unselecting the old one, instead of coordinates of the newly selected one.

Comment: Besides explicitly remembering the last selected point and checking for this, any ideas how to achieve wanted behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply compare actual point to be unselected with array of actually selected points. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/2Wr8v/1/

```
unselect: function(event) {
    var p = this.series.chart.getSelectedPoints();
    if(p.length > 0 && p[0].x == this.x) {
        $('#label').text('point unselected');
    }
}
```